# Why I got the Timeout error when using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, puppeteer

What should I do when I get a timeout error for async tests and hooks?

[image]

My code is :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
 describe('My First Puppeteer Test', () =>{

   it('should launch the browser', async function(){
        
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 500});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
 
        await browser.close();
       
    })

})
```

Comment: It's up to you what you should do. You can increase the test case timeout, move the `puppeteer.launch()` to a `beforeAll` block, remove `slowMo`, make it headless, or some combination of these that makes sense for whatever your use case happens to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default timeout for all navigation operations using:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(10000);
```

Or you can also set the timeout for a specific `page.goto` operation using:

```js
await page.goto('https://www.google.com', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 10000});
```